# Create Table from array with only Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I've been trying for about 2 days now to create a table from an array with pure Javascript. What I want in the future is to be able to pull data from a database and allow JS to create the table for me.

**What I WANT to happen is for Javascript to create this**

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>item</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>01/02/20</td>
            <td>32.99</td>
            <td>Pencil</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>08/12/21</td>
            <td>94.88</td>
            <td>Food</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>04/01/22</td>
            <td>32.11</td>
            <td>tax</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*and so on*

The problem I'm encountering right now is that I can get JS to create the table, append `<thead>` and ,`<th>` with the correct headings, as well as make a new `<tr>` and `<tbody>` tags. But when I come to adding the data  tags from the multidimensional array, I can't make it/figure out how to get JS to add new `<tr>` tags when needed.

As such, my table is just three headings and 9 datapoints all in the same row.

My code

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <style>
        #tableContainer {
           
        }

        #theTable {
            border: 3px dashed black;
            width: 30vw;
            height: auto;
            /* display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;*/
        }
        #theTable tr{
            background-color: green;
           
        }
        #theTable td{
            background-color: red;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="tableContainer">
      <table id="theTable">
      </table>
    </div>
 
    <script src="tablepractice.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```js
// Create variables to hold all the table elements I may need
let table = document.getElementById("theTable");
let tableContainer = document.getElementById("tableCointainer");

//let tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
let tableHeader = document.createElement("thead");
let tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
let textNode = document.createTextNode("£");


// Data fields
const columnName = ["date", "price", "item"];
const tableInputs = [
    ["01/02/20", `32.99`, "Pencil"],
    ["08/12/21", "94.88", "Food"],
    ["04/01/22", "32.11", "tax"],
    ["09/04/22", "83.12", "brake pads"]
];

// Create the table
createTable();

function createTable() {
    let tableRow = document.createElement("tr");    
    table.appendChild(tableHeader);
    tableHeader.appendChild(tableRow);

    columnName.forEach((index) => {
        let thElement = document.createElement("th");
        thElement.textContent = index;
        console.log(thElement);
        tableRow.appendChild(thElement);
    })

    addTableData();    
}

function addTableData() {
    let tableBodyRow = document.createElement("tr");
    
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    tableBody.appendChild(tableBodyRow);

    tableInputs.forEach((index) => {
        tableBody.appendChild(tableBodyRow);
        
        index.forEach((innerIndex) => {

            let tableDataField = document.createElement("td");

            //console.log(innerIndex);
            tableDataField.textContent = innerIndex;
            //console.log(tableDataField);
            tableBodyRow.appendChild(tableDataField);
        })
    })
}


    /*
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    tableBody.appendChild(tableBodyRow);
    for (i = 0; i < tableInputs.length; i++) {
        console.log("position " + tableInputs[i])
        tableBody.appendChild(tableBodyRow2);
        for (j = 0; j < tableInputs[i].length; j++) {

            
            let tableData = document.createElement("td");
            console.log(tableInputs[i][j]);


            tableData.textContent = tableInputs[j];
            tableBodyRow.appendChild(tableData);
        }
    }
    */
}
```

I've attempted to use nested for loops which, whilst worked and created all `<td>` elements I needed, wouldn't let me amend a new `<tr>`. I've tried using if statements such as
`if (j > 3) { tableBody.appendChild(tableDataRow)};`
which again hasn't worked, or when I have made it work, I get something like

```html
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
```

at the end of my Javascript generated code in the inspector.

I then also tried nested `forEach()` loops as I read it's better to use `forEach()` as it's an array method, but again I can get that to create 9 inline datarows, but can't figure out how to create a new `<tr>` using it.

I've also moved the `let` for the tableRow elements within the for loops and the `forEach()` methods, as well as creating a new `let` named `let tableRowData2 = document.createElement("tr");` to see if it's a confliction that Javascript is overwriting the original `<tr>` it created, but that didn't help either.

Any assistance on this matter will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You really should be using the [TableElement API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) to make life easy when creating a table.
Useful methods to create rows `.insertRow()` and cells `.insertCell()` within `.createTHead()` or `.createTBody()`

```js
const columnName = ["date", "price", "item"];
const tableInputs = [
    ["01/02/20", `32.99`, "Pencil"],
    ["08/12/21", "94.88", "Food"],
    ["04/01/22", "32.11", "tax"],
    ["09/04/22", "83.12", "brake pads"]
];

function createTable() {
    const table = document.createElement("table");
    table.setAttribute("border", "1");

    // Loop columnName for headers
    const thead = table.createTHead();
    const headerRow = thead.insertRow();
    for (const column of columnName) {
        const headerCell = headerRow.insertCell();
        headerCell.textContent = column;
    }

    // Loop tableInputs for row data
    const tbody = table.createTBody();
    for (const rowDataArray of tableInputs) {
        const row = tbody.insertRow();

        for (let r = 0; r < rowDataArray.length; r++) {
            const cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.textContent = rowDataArray[r];
        }
    }

    // Append to table
    table.appendChild(thead);
    table.appendChild(tbody);

    // Add table to page
    const tableContainer = document.getElementById("tableContainer");
    tableContainer.appendChild(table);
}
createTable();
```

```html
<div id="tableContainer">    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Cleaned it right up. So then I'm right in assuming that if I'm now pulling data from databases into arrays (whether from JSON or otherwise) this code will dynamically update the table and create one with all the elements in it?

Also, I guess I would use .setAttribute("class","nameofclass"); in order to style it with CSS?

Comment: @Ruzzy100, np. I updated answer to include `.createTHead()` and `.createTBody()`

Comment: @Ruzzy100, yes this snippet would dynamically change your table so it's data driven. Now if you change how it's stored from Arrays to JSON then you might need some tweaking but the end goal is the same.  Customize table how you see fit, `.setAttribute("class","nameofclass")` will do the trick or `table.className = "nameofclass";`